# Is mysql database logic suitable for query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am designing a database,  and I would like to know;

Can I answer this question with queries, how much skill employees earned from this trainings?

Is this a good structure to do it?

- how much money spent per department
- how much skill earned per employee
- how much skill earned per department

```
 id session_name    Skill         impact    sugg dept   function    training_value  training no
 1  PHP             Software        3       Sales       2           100usd          1   
 2  PHP             Software        3        Finance    2           100usd    1
 3  PHP             communication   2        Sales      2           100usd    1
 4  PHP             communication   2        Finance    2           100usd    1
 5  ASP             Software        4        Sales      2           200usd          2   
 6  ASP             Software        4        Finance    2           200usd    2
 7  ASP             database        1        Sales      2           200usd    2
 8  ASP             database        1        Finance    2           200usd    2


attended training table
id student_id  training_no
1  1           1
1  1           2


student table
id    name  department
1     John  1
2     Mary  2

department table
id  name
1   sales
2   finance
```

In the end I need to find skills for each student

```
john
software      7
communication 2
database      1

total spent 
john 300 usd

total spent by department
sales 300 usd
```

Answer (score 3):

Your schema looks OK to me.

You should, however, think about entities and relationships.

Your entities seem to be trainings, people, and departments.

You have a many:many relationship for people:trainings. That's good.
You have a one:many relationship for departments:people. That's also good.

It looks like you want some kind of relationship for trainings:departments. I'm guessing here, but you have a `sugg dept` column in your trainings table. Is that supposed to have a direct relationship to your departments table?

Do you actually need an extra entity called "attendance" rather than just a many-to-many relationship people:trainings.  Do you want to record when a person did a training? Do you want to record how much that particular attendance cost?  How about what marks they received if there was a quiz?

In that case, you'll want relationships where each person has zero or more attendances, each attendance has exactly one training, and each training has zero or more attendances.

My point: do the hard work of thinking through your entities and relationships, and the result will be a good design for your tables.

If I may put it another way: What part of the real world are you trying to capture in your data base? What's valuable in the real world that you want your data base to hold?  In your application ...

- Students are people. They are, umm, inherently valuable and persistent entities.
- Trainings represent the labor and cost of creating them and presenting them.
- Attendances represent the effort of students.
- Departments probably pay the bill for attendances. They certainly represent power centers in your application.

What other items of value exist in this corner of the real world? Teachers? Managers? Venues (classrooms)?  Equipment?  Customers?

My point is, figure out your entities -- the items of value -- and the relationships between them. Then write your table definitions.

Comment: Great point that cannot be emphasized enough: build your model on conceptual and logical levels first, only then start tinkering with tables!

Comment: Thank you. Logic is when a student login to system. student can only see trainings suggested to his department and his function. that is why same training lists 4 time at my table. when I get a training I get multi skill. Like PHP gives me coding skill +4 but also gives me database skills +2. In the end I want to see payment per person, per skill, per employee.